# How to create a ValidationContext from scratch?

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflow

I'm using Spring Webflow for an application and I need to validate a model object outside of the "normal" webflow validation cycle.   I'm using a separate validation class:

```
@Component
public class MyInfoValidator {
    public void validateMyInfo(MyInfoView myInfo, ValidationContext context) {
        MessageContext messages = context.getMessageContext();
[snip]
    }
}
```

I'd like to call this same validation class from another part of my code and validate the object, but I need to create (or retrieve) a ValidationContext object.

Can anyone tell me how to do this?   Is it floating around somewhere in one of the Webflow beans or do I have to create one from scratch?

Comment: August 2017, I need to do the same and it so disappointing to seeing that none has answered  xD